# Ошибка Debian 8.6 insserv: warning

Tags: linux, debian

Добрую ночь, хотел спросить кто-то сталкивался с этим и как оно лечится?

```
insserv: warning: script 'expanddisk' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

Ломаю голову второй час, но понять не могу.

Comment: ошибка вам прямо говорит, что скрипт не соответствует стандарту lsb https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Answer (score 4):

это не ошибка, это предупреждение (буквальное значение слова *warning*).

> missing LSB tags and overrides

означает, что в старт-стоповом скрипте `expanddisk` (находящемся в каталоге `/etc/init.d`) отсутствуют определяемые [стандартом lsb заголовки](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html).

инструкция по «lsb-фикации» старт-стоповых скриптов в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux»: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

пример заголовков (их смысл изложен в приведённых выше ссылках):

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Все работает корректно

Comment: @Дмитрий, если ответ вам пог отметьте его галочкой как принятый.